Conditional Router Wos2 Runtime error occurred while mediating the message java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
I'm trying to implement simple example about conditional-router mediator this is the API XML code
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/conditional-router-based-on-body" name="BodyConditionalRouterAPI" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <log description="log request" level="full"/>
            <conditionalRouter continueAfter="true" description="route depend on property in the request called transactionType which can be DEPIT or CREDIT or REVERSAL">
                <conditionalRoute asynchronous="true" breakRoute="true">
                    <condition>
                        <equal source="//transactionType" type="soap" value="DEPIT"/>
                    </condition>
                    <target sequence="DepitSEQ"/>
                </conditionalRoute>
                <conditionalRoute asynchronous="true" breakRoute="true">
                    <condition>
                        <equal source="//transactionType" type="soap" value="CREDIT"/>
                    </condition>
                    <target sequence="CreditSEQ"/>
                </conditionalRoute>
            </conditionalRouter>
            <log description="log msg after preparing it from selected route/sequence" level="full"/>
            <respond/>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence/>
        <faultSequence/>
    </resource>
</api>

and this is the sequences that will route to it depend on each condition
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="CreditSEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="log to indicate that the transactionType was CREDIT" level="custom">
        <property name="body routing" value="DEPIT"/>
    </log>
</sequence>




<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="DepitSEQ" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log description="log to indicate that the transactionType was DEPIT" level="custom">
        <property name="body routing" value="DEPIT"/>
    </log>
    <payloadFactory description="prepare json msg" media-type="json">
        <format>{&#xd;
"body-routing" : "DEPIT FLOW"&#xd;
}</format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
</sequence>

and this is the logs of the app
[2024-06-30 14:16:54,189]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:BodyConditionalRouterAPI} To: /conditional-router-based-on-body, MessageID: urn:uuid:eb488b34-9b88-4c91-b372-aec77dd4d808, correlation_id: eb488b34-9b88-4c91-b372-aec77dd4d808, Direction: request, Payload: {
    "transactionType": "DEPIT"
}
[2024-06-30 14:16:54,189]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:BodyConditionalRouterAPI} To: /conditional-router-based-on-body, MessageID: urn:uuid:eb488b34-9b88-4c91-b372-aec77dd4d808, correlation_id: eb488b34-9b88-4c91-b372-aec77dd4d808, Direction: request, Payload: {
    "transactionType": "DEPIT"
}
[2024-06-30 14:16:54,189]  INFO {LogMediator} - {api:BodyConditionalRouterAPI} body routing = DEPIT
[2024-06-30 14:16:54,196] ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:BodyConditionalRouterAPI} Runtime error occurred while mediating the message java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$PrivateEntryIterator.nextEntry(TreeMap.java:1208)
    at java.base/java.util.TreeMap$KeyIterator.next(TreeMap.java:1262)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.PassThroughTransportUtils.removeUnwantedHeadersFromHeaderMap(PassThroughTransportUtils.java:142)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.PassThroughTransportUtils.removeUnwantedHeaders(PassThroughTransportUtils.java:122)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.PassThroughHttpSender.invoke(PassThroughHttpSender.java:251)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.send(AxisEngine.java:442)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2Sender.sendBack(Axis2Sender.java:217)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.RespondMediator.mediate(RespondMediator.java:46)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:110)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:72)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:158)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.Resource.process(Resource.java:342)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.API.process(API.java:477)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.apiProcess(AbstractApiHandler.java:94)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.AbstractApiHandler.dispatchToAPI(AbstractApiHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RestRequestHandler.java:90)
    at org.apache.synapse.api.rest.RestRequestHandler.process(RestRequestHandler.java:76)
    at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:54)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:346)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:101)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:379)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:438)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:186)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

[2024-06-30 14:19:25,310]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2024-06-30 14:19:25,311]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /conditional-router-based-on-body, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:57462, CONNECTION http-incoming-5 Correlation ID : 5a3854d0-5623-422b-b3b9-68d94ccfef58
[2024-06-30 14:19:55,021]  INFO {SourceHandler} - Writer null when calling informWriterError
[2024-06-30 14:19:55,021]  WARN {SourceHandler} - STATE_DESCRIPTION = Socket Timeout occurred after accepting the request headers and the request body, INTERNAL_STATE = REQUEST_DONE, DIRECTION = REQUEST, CAUSE_OF_ERROR = Connection between the client and the EI timeouts, HTTP_URL = /conditional-router-based-on-body, HTTP_METHOD = POST, SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 180000, CLIENT_ADDRESS = /127.0.0.1:57484, CONNECTION http-incoming-6 Correlation ID : eb488b34-9b88-4c91-b372-aec77dd4d808

I expect that the behaviour of app can edit on the message in any sequence that the conditional-router routes to

most of the solutions i found on the web suggest to use Switch Mediator instead of Conditional-Router, i know i can do it using Multiple Switchs or Multiple Filter Mediators, the question still why wso2 team still make Conditional-Router Mediator available in the tool ?
